# Keep the current tab on the Windows 8 task manager between sessions?

Tags: windows-8, task-manager

In older versions of the Windows Task Manager (like Windows 7) it saved what tab I had open between sessions. Is there a way to do this in the new Win8 Task Manager? It always defaults to Processes and I prefer Details.

Comment: this is not possible in Win8 :(

Comment: @magicandre1981 That's just wonderful. :(

Comment: welcome to the world of oversimplification in Windows 8.

Comment: @magicandre1981 I did notice that. And while I like some of the features of the new Task Manager, I miss the old one.